# Create a button from an Android Activity and position it properly

Tags: android, layout, button, android-activity

The app I'm working on requires me to display buttons according to a config file the user specifies. Because of this, I'm not able to use the layout.xml to specify where a button should be placed, and have to create and position button from within my Activity.I want my app to support Android 2.3 as well, which rules out the .setLeft() and .setTop() methods.

As best I can tell I've got to position all the buttons using LayoutParams, but I'm not seeing any way to position the Buttons, only adjust their size.

Any pointers on the best way to implement this would be great.

Edit: Grid Layout was suggested, but it wasn't introduced until API 14, so it's no good either.

Comment: you can still use margins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For RelativeLayout, what about setMargin(x,x,x,x) instead of setLeft setTop

Comment: That did it! I think in my previous attempts to use setMargin I kept setting the last two too high and driving the button off the edge of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the type of layout you use. If you use a `RelativeLayout`, for example, you'll need to specify the alignment rules using a [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html). The same will be true for a `LinearLayout`, `GridLayout` or any other layout type.

Comment: For now I've been using the RelativeLayout, but I think the Grid Layout may be a better choice for what I'm actually doing.

Comment: Grid Layout wasn't introduced until API 14, which means I still can't use it for this app. Thanks for the suggestion though.